# Formatting numbers in different cultures

Tags: c#, .net, cultureinfo

**Assuming an invariant culture**, is it possible to define a different group separator in the format - than the comma?

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:#,##0}", 2295));
```

Output:

```
2,295
```

Desired output:

```
2.295
```

The invariant culture is a requirement because currencies from many different locales are being formatted with format strings, that have been user defined. Ie for Denmark they have defined the price format to be "{0:0},-", while for Ireland it might be "€{0:#,##0}".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you have different format strings, this does not mean that you have to use InvariantCulture. If you have a format string for germany e.g. you format this string using the Culture("de-de"):

```
String.Format(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo( "de-de" ), "{0:0},-", 2295) //will result in 2.295,-
String.Format(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo( "en-us" ), "{0:0},-", 2295) //will result in 2,295,-
```

Alternatively you can specify your custom [number format info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

```
NumberFormatInfo nfi = new NumberFormatInfo( )
{
    CurrencyGroupSeparator = ":"
};
String.Format(nfi, "{0:0},-", 2295) //will result in 2:295,-
```

Comment: I do not understand your answer. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I was not clear enough. I did not have the information about what culture it was (at least not directly in an "en-us"-kinda format. So I was hoping to let the customer write their priceformatting-strings in a universal format without regards for what culture it would be executed under. 

I guess that is not possible, so I added a column with the culture-identified and use it as you describe above. :)

Answer (score 3):

The normal approach would be to *not* use an Invariant culture.

You do specify the formatting in Invariant style, but the proper symbols would be substituted, `#,##0.00` will come out as **1.234,50** or as **1,235.50** depending on the actual culture used.