# decimal format c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following problem: i need to convert a decimal number to string. Example:
11.350 (eleven thousand three hundreds fifty)

code

```
lbl_valorBuyin.Text =   
   (Valid.GetDecimal(TORNEO.RBUYIN) + 
     Valid.GetDecimal(TORNEO.VALORBOUNTY)).ToString("###,###");
```

and the output is 11,350 and i want it to be 11.350. It´s not clear for me the use of format when converting decimal values to string.

I have tried differents formats, but not case. I couldn´t work it out.

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where in the world do you use . as the number group separator?

Comment: [This page](http://www.xencraft.com/resources/multi-currency.html) suggests German currency as being formated as `1.234.567.890,12` for example.

Comment: @Jonas: A much larger [chunk of the world](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:DecimalSeparator.svg) than one might think.

Comment: @Paul That map shows decimal separator usage and not thousand separator. It seems most countries using comma and decimal separator then uses space as thousand separator. Germany is not one of them. I totally forgot about Germany. Bad mistake.

Comment: @Jonas: I assumed wrongly those using one of `,`, `.` would use the other for the thousands separator. See [examples of use](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thousands_separator#Examples_of_use) on Wikipedia from where I found that image for more descriptive list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like [Formatting numbers in different cultures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6110068/formatting-numbers-in-different-cultures/6110189#6110189)

Answer (score 2):

Use `.ToString("N2");`

This will format your number using the current culture.

If you don't need decimal places use `.ToString("N0");`

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
ToString("0,###");
```

---

Refer to [Decimal.ToString Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzeeb5cd.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
.ToString("0.000", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: I thought the invariant culture used comma as the thousands separator?

Comment: @Paul Ruane, that's correct. I thought that he wants to use `.` as decimal separator. Maybe I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try `.ToString("#\\.###");`

I ran a little test and `(11350.0).ToString("#\\.###")` gave me an output of 11.350

Answer (score 0):

For a quick formatting like what you want:

```
.ToString("###,###", new NumberFormatInfo() { NumberGroupSeparator = "." });
```

It's in the [IFormatProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) passed to `ToString` that are defined all separators and formatting properties.